# A lot of database migrations files

Tags: php, database, symfony, migration

I'm using database migrations with PHP symfony framework and I noticed that there are a lot of files, and when I build my project and every time many files (migrations) are executed.

What is best practice to manage migrations? Could I delete them and create only one database dump file, for database initiation?

Comment: You should use fixtures for you dev database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Doctrine Migrations to create these files. On dev you can always regenerate the database using the doctrine:schema:update command.
When setting up a new instance you can also use the doctrine:schema:create command which will also create the latest table definitions for you.

That brings us to your question; do you need to keep all the migrations? As long as you know that the migrations have been executed on outdated instances you can safely archive (my preferred option) or delete them as they will never be called again.

Comment: Yes I'm using Doctrine migrations, and I run them when I build my project before deploying to production. Shouldn't I use migrations for building the project and better use doctrine:schema:create?

Comment: No schema:create is only for dev purposes as it doesn't take your data into account. Use migrations execute for deployments, create for dev/test.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use migrations on production instead of doctrine:schema:update, because you can have some problems while updating process. It is always a better option IMO to keep an eye on what happens with the DB.

On development env you can easily use doctrine:schema:update command but you should use migrations on production. In some cases the command may brake the migrations (it happened to me a few times).

Comment: Ok, but how do you manage you migrations when you have a lot of them? Also how do you build your project (if you build on CI/CD)? Do you use migrations or schema create?

Comment: you have to do them with sense :) it is better to make fewer migrations (not for every new field in table separately) but one big migration. When you finish your feature you can merge multiple migrations into one before pushing it to the master branch.